# Cannot connect from MySQL Workbench to dockerized MySQL server

Tags: java, mysql, docker, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to connect from the MySQL Workbench to my dockerized mysql server. I'm using Windows 10. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

# package updates & install mysql
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y mysql-server
RUN apt-get -y install supervisor

ADD supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf

# bind sql script
ADD musicdb.sql /tmp/musicdb.sql

RUN sed -i -e"s/^bind-address\s*=\s*127.0.0.1/bind-address = 0.0.0.0/" /etc/mysql/my.cnf

EXPOSE 3306

RUN /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &" && \
sleep 5 && \
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE musicdb" && \
mysql -u root musicdb < /tmp/musicdb.sql

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

I'm using this library to create, run, etc. the container from Java:

https://github.com/spotify/docker-client

My actual method to do this in Java is:

```
    public static void createContainerWithPorts(){
        DockerClient docker;


        try {
            docker = DefaultDockerClient.fromEnv().build();

//PortBindings
            Map<String, List<PortBinding>> portBindings = new HashMap<>();

            List<PortBinding> hostPorts = new ArrayList<>();

            hostPorts.add(PortBinding.of("0.0.0.0", "3306"));
            portBindings.put("3306", hostPorts);

            HostConfig hostConfig = HostConfig.builder().portBindings(portBindings).build();
            ContainerConfig containerConfig = ContainerConfig.builder().hostConfig(hostConfig).image("mysql-container").exposedPorts("3306").build();

//create container
            ContainerCreation contaierCreation = docker.createContainer(containerConfig);
            String id = contaierCreation.id();

//start container
            docker.startContainer(id);

            ContainerInfo containerInfo = docker.inspectContainer(id);
            System.out.println(containerInfo.toString());

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            scanner.next();
            docker.killContainer(id);
            docker.removeContainer(id);
            docker.close();
        } catch (DockerCertificateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (DockerException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Java builds the Container fine from the before created Docker Image. When I'm looking on actual running Docker Container it looks that the port binding works. When I access my container with `docker exec -it SQLContainer bash` it works fine and I can access my SQL server.

When i try to connect with MySQL Workbench, I got the error message shown in the picture below:
[MySQL Workbench Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWEoy.jpg)

Does someone know what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a new user for your mysql server and specify from where the user can be used. This is because root access is only available through localhost I believe.

So to create a new user, you need to add a little something to the RUN command where you start your server:

```
RUN /bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/mysqld_safe &" && \
sleep 5 && \
mysql -u root -e "CREATE DATABASE musicdb" && \
mysql -u root musicdb < /tmp/musicdb.sql && \
mysql -u root -e "CREATE USER 'newUser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'somePassword'" && \
mysql -u root -e "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newUser'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION"
```

That way you create a new user with the name `newUser` that can access from anywhere.